# Xcode single console pane amongst tabs

Tags: xcode, tabs

Is there a way in Xcode 5 to consolidate the console pane/view/area between tabs into a single console?

I have multiple tabs open, each for a source file I am editing.  Every time I run the app from a different tab I have to adjust the console in that tab.  It's annoying.  Any suggestions?